# Angular: How to inject custom directives into component

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a directive I'm using like this:

```
<input (ifValid)="save()">Save</input>
```

Into my component I'm trying to inject it into constructor.

```
@Component(...)
export class Comp {

    constructor(
        MyCustomDirective directive
    ) {}

}
```

However, I'm getting a error message telling me that there's no any provider for my directive.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `MyCustomDirective` defined in `providers` in `NgModule`?

Comment: You should change your html to: `<input ifValid (ifValid)="save()">Save</input>`

Comment: No, it isn't. But I've been able to use it without adding it into any `providers` clause. When I've added it into my component dependency error raises... why?

Comment: `@ViewChild(SubmitValidationDirective, { static: true }) ifValid;`

Comment: You can use your custom directive selector in html tags. if `selector: '[google-place]'` you can use `<input type="text" google-place />`

Answer (score 0):

1. Your usage of directive seems to be incorrect. Putting paranthesis makes it an event. Like a click event. Directive are used like `<input ifValid>Save</input>`
2. The error that you are getting is because Angular does not know, you have created a new custom directive, called ifValid. So you have to tell angular, in Ngmodule as :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [IfValidDirective],
```

You can learn more about Directives [here](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#write-the-directive-code)

---

I believe you are trying to save user-input, only if the input is a valid text. I don't think directive is needed here.
You can try something like this:

```
<input type="button" (click)="save()">

//in your component
save() {
  // check if the input is valid or not  
}
```